# using the result of a UILabel after a calculation in another calculation in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uilabel

I hope what I'm about makes sense.  what I am trying to do is use the result of say a - b = c. 
Now "a" and "b" are both UITextfields and "C" is a `UILabel`.

I want to be able to use the result of "c" to take "a" place each time the calculation is run.

Example:  100 - 30 = 70,  then the next time I want to add another figure in position "b", "a" is now result of "c".

Now I also want to keep the original result of "a" in the textfield I entered first so I have it as a reference point. but would like to have the "c" result to drop each time I enter a figure into "b". now how do I code this?

The first part I have but not the second part.

heres my first part of the code

```
-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {
NSString *spCash = self.spendingCash.text;
NSString *recAmount = self.receiptAmount.text;


float cashFloat;
float receiptFloat =[recAmount floatValue];
float spendingFloat = [spCash floatValue];

cashFloat = spendingFloat - receiptFloat;

NSString *cashAv = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"$%.2f", cashFloat];

self.cashAvailable.text = cashAv;
```

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks for your time and look forward to reading some responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't depend on storing data in UI elements.

Create properties (probably in your view controller) to represent the numbers that people enter and the results of your calculations.  That way you can save whatever information you need and not depend on whether or not it's visible on the screen.

Comment: not quite sure what you mean?  I want the user to see the result of C and each time its adjusted. can you suggest a different way to put it.

Comment: You can update your label with the calculation result whenever you want.  The point is to think of (and store) the numbers you're working with separate from what you see instead of thinking in terms of subtracting two text fields to get a label.  If you want to update your question with the code you're using for "the first part", I'll try to be more specific about suggesting changes.

Comment: I've added in the code i use for the first part.  now I want to re sue the result of the cashAvailable as the spending cash after this first calc is finished

Comment: Right, so the important part is `floatcashAvailable`.  Make that a property of the class this code is in instead of a local variable and then you can reuse `self.floatcashAvailable` on the next calculation.

Comment: thanks for your help.  I will admit I am very new to this so please accept my lack of knowledge.  so you mean I need to put an @property in the header file for floatcashAvailable? I imagine I will need to put something under the implementation as well? how would I code this as an equation?  so it runs until the amount reaches 0?

Comment: If those things are giving you trouble, I suggest taking a step back and studying something like http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html that gives you a good overview of the language.  Just typing stuff that strangers tell you to type is a road to more pain.  :-)

Comment: i have updated the code I am using Phillip.  now I haven't made a seperate class for the calculation but after doing some reading I think I may need one for the second part then initialise it. can you please confirm if Im on the right track here.  thanks

Comment: also I have changed it to a uitextfield instead of the uilabel.

Comment: It's possible that having the calculations in a separate class would make the logic clearer for you...no guarantee.  :-)  The important point, whichever way you structure it, is to treat text fields as things that show results and accept edits rather than places to store data.  (Are you letting the user change values?  If not, use labels.)

Comment: I've been reading a bit and would a while loop suit this purpose? I have also changed it back to a uilabel as you said I don't want the user to be able to change the result field only the fields for spending and receipt amount.?